# Disable dropdown opening on select2 clear

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Seems that select2 4 opens by default the dropdown when clearing the current selected item. Previous versions of select2 didn't seem to have that behaviour and I'm trying to achieve it but no luck for now.

Does anyone know how to hook into the clear event so we can disable it's default behaviour and clear the selected option without opening the dropdown?

Cheers,
Al

Comment: Assuming that this is a single select, you can `preventDefault` on the `select2:closing` event that is triggered right after `select2:unselect`. At another time I can write up a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I  had a try but I get the error "Cannot set property 'prevented' of undefined" when preventDefault on select2:closing. I've put together a quick fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/r56zh872/ any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @KevinBrown Is there any upstream issue created for this situation?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Not that I consider it a bug, [but this ticket was opened about it](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can confirm, preventing events seems to not work for some reason, so you can just close the dropdown after some timeout:

```
$("select").select2({
    allowClear: true
}).on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {
    $(this).data('state', 'unselected');
}).on("select2:open", function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('state') === 'unselected') {
        $(this).removeData('state'); 

        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.select2('close');
        }, 1);
    }    
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/obq3yLf2/

Comment: Cheers Sam. Good workaround until the preventing issue gets solved.

Comment: Its better the second solution, without timeOut

Comment: I also had to go this route, but it still showed for a brief moment, which I didn't like. To fix that, I added a style like this: "body.hide-select2-dropdown .select2-dropdown { display: none; }". Then, where we remove the "state" data, I added this class to my body element. Finally, after calling "select2('close')", I removed this class from my body element. That seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 87):

You don't require a timeout to make this work, here's my example:

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    allowClear: true
}).on('select2:unselecting', function() {
    $(this).data('unselecting', true);
}).on('select2:opening', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('unselecting')) {
        $(this).removeData('unselecting');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I have multiple select2 in a page ?

Comment: I assume you mean applying the above to multiple select2 elements? In that case you replace `#my-select` with maybe `.selects` and add the class to your select elements.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with a short delay after deselecting one of the items and this solution fixed that issue for me:

```
$(this).select2({
    multiple: 'multiple',
}).on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.select2('close');
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $("select").select2({
        allowClear: true
    }).on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
        $(this).data('unselecting', true);
    }).on("select2:opening", function (e) {
        if ($(this).data('unselecting')) {
            $(this).removeData('unselecting');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

This will work without any flickering of body while closing/clearing the select2 component.
Add the above code anywhere in js.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple Implementation:

```
$('select').on('select2:unselect', function(evt) {
    $(this).select2({
        placeholder : {
            id : '',
            text : '---None Selected---'
        },
        allowClear : true,
        theme : "bootstrap"
    }).select2('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="my-select">
<option>Test1</option>
<option>Test2</option>
<option>Test3</option>
</select>



<script>
$('#my-select').select2().on('select2:opening', function(currentEvent) {
  currentEvent.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).