# Select2: do not reopen on unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 select, with `allowClear: true`.

At the moment, when I unselect an option (clicking on 'X' after any selection), the select reopens. I want it to remain closed instead.

Live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/proxJX

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618382/disable-dropdown-opening-on-select2-clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dropdown opening on select2 clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618382/disable-dropdown-opening-on-select2-clear)